# REST API controller name discarded (ignored)

Tags: .net-core, controller, rest

In a REST API project dotnet Core 5.0, I have two controllers: MyAController and MyBController in separate classes. They derive from MediatorApiController that derives from ControllerBase. They are mainly identical except for the entity they manage (CRUD). When I type https://localhost:5001/api it goes to the  [HttpGet("/{lang}")] corresponding method in MyAController and display the objects {lang}='api' ??.

If I type  https://localhost:5001/api/MyA/1 or https://localhost:5001/api/MyB/1 I receive an error
*Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints*
MyAController.Get
MyBController.Get ???

Can anyone help ?
I did use edi.routedebugger, but it does not get to it (error 500), if I display the controllers they are all shown properly.

```
 public class AController : MediatorApiController
 public class BController : MediatorApiController
 public class MediatorApiController : ControllerBase

 
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
 public class MyAController : MediatorApiController
 {
    [HttpGet("/{lang}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<AlimentDto>>> GetAll(string lang)
    {
        return await Mediator.Send(new GetAllAlimentsQuery(lang));
    }

    [HttpGet("/{id}/{lang}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<AlimentDto>> Get(int id, string lang)
    {
      return await Mediator.Send(new GetAlimentByIdQuery { Id = id, Lang = lang });
    }
```

}

startup.cs file:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwaggerUi3();
                app.UseRouteDebugger();
            }
            //app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseOpenApi();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove "/", make it

```
 [HttpGet("{lang}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<AlimentDto>>> GetAll(string lang)
```

for lang=en your url should be

```
../api/MyAControlle/en
```

But I prefer and recomend  to use  the full route attribute

```
 [Route("~/api/MyAControlle/GetAll/{lang}]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<AlimentDto>>> GetAll(string lang)
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, How come I did not see that extra slash in the httpGet ?? https://localhost:5001/api/myA/en and
https://localhost:5001/api/myA/1/en are working fine with the slash removed.
Now it is obvious that the slash was  getting on top of the route from the controller itself.